# PagedList pager doesn't increment page number or routes to the specified controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm having problems with [X.PagedList](https://github.com/dncuug/X.PagedList) package. I'm using.net core mvc 2.2 for the project. Whatever I do the PagedListPager doesn't seem to work. It doesn't increment the page number and can't change the controller or action in it.

This is the controller

```
    public IActionResult CategoryPairing(int? page = 1, int? pageSize = 25)
    {            
        TrendyolCategoryPairVM trendyolCategoryPairVM = new TrendyolCategoryPairVM()
        {
            Categories = _categoryService.GetCategoriesAsIQueryable().ToPagedList((int)page, (int)pageSize),
            TrendyolCategories = _trendyolCategoryService.GetAllCategories().Categories.Map(p => true, (NodeDTO n) => { return n.SubCategories; }).ToList()
        };

        return View(trendyolCategoryPairVM);
    }
```

And the pager

```
    @Html.PagedListPager((IPagedList)Model.Categories, page => Url.Action("Whatever","controller", new { page = page }),
        new X.PagedList.Mvc.Core.Common.PagedListRenderOptions
        {
            DisplayItemSliceAndTotal = true,
            ContainerDivClasses = new[] { "navigation" },
            LiElementClasses = new[] { "page-item" },
            PageClasses = new[] { "page-link" },
        });
```

This one should route to the controller/whatever with the page number specified, but it just routes to the same page without a page number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find out that X.PagedLists pager has some problems when it comes to .net core 2.2. Related issues can be found in [here](https://github.com/dncuug/X.PagedList/issues/131) and [here](https://github.com/dncuug/X.PagedList/issues/133)
.